# Creating a SQL Server 2012 Query with a SUBQUERY and a JOIN statement, need a second pair of eyes?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, adventureworks

I am trying to code an SQL Server 2012 Query using the AdventureWorks 2012 database as part of a school assignment and I created my query but i am unsure if it is clean enough and properly configured.

I am supposed to Use a Subquery and a Join statement together.

> "Return the customerid & territory id from the Customer table where
>   the name on the SalesTerritory table is ‘Central’"

I am not asking for help to cheat in any way, i just need a second pair of eyes because i am having a tough time figuring this out, I am barely able to program and have little love for it.

Here is my Query so far:

```
SELECT Sales.Customer.CustomerID
       , Sales.Customer.TerritoryID,Sales.SalesTerritory.Name
FROM  Sales.Customer 
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory 
    ON Sales.Customer.TerritoryID = Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID
WHERE (Sales.SalesTerritory.Name = N'central')
```

Comment: This query returns all customers where their territory is central. Right?

Comment: Yes, I'm not very good at programming in general but that's exactly what i need to do. The results file does what i need it to do but i want to make sure i coded the query properly to meet the requirements. This tends to be a confusing subject with me.

Comment: Instead of doing a regular INNER JOIN on the SalesTerritory table, do a join on a subquery of SalesTerritory where Name = 'central' and you'll have your required query.

Comment: OK I'll have to try again i guess, Thanks for your input Jens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Sales.Customer.CustomerID, Sales.Customer.TerritoryID,    SalesTerritoryFiltered.Name
FROM   Sales.Customer 
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM Sales.SalesTerritory
            WHERE Sales.SalesTerritory.Name = N'central') SalesTerritoryFiltered
  ON Sales.Customer.TerritoryID  = SalesTerritoryFiltered.TerritoryID
```

This one has an inner join and subquery containing your filtered results. Untested but should work.

Comment: OK so i see where i made my mistake at, i see now how you did the Sub-query. I just need more practice i Guess.  I'll make the changes you have suggested and try it out.

Comment: Just to be clear. You did not really make any mistake. I would normally write my query like you did, but given the request to use join & subquery this is an alternative solution. I try to avoid subqueries whenever I can because I feel they reduce readability.

Comment: Your correction to my code works like a charm and I'm surprised that both versions produce the same result!

Comment: @JacobHeckman: Jens has written query to accomplish your task (so I upvote him), but for clearness, this solution is more expensive about performance. Your query (encapsulated in your question) is good.

Comment: Edited: (I Up-voted Jens for his assistance) Well thank you for the vote of confidence, I gave you a check-mark for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `WHERE` with `AND` this make filtering criteria more efficient and results in reducing number of row fetching while joining the table.so this may help in improving performance as well !

```
SELECT Sales.Customer.CustomerID
      ,Sales.Customer.TerritoryID,Sales.SalesTerritory.Name
FROM  Sales.Customer 
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory 
ON Sales.Customer.TerritoryID = Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID
AND Sales.SalesTerritory.Name = N'central'
```

Comment: Unfortunately the teacher made it clear that we had to use a Where statement until later on in the semester. It's just that we receive little input or direction until after grading, so you can imagine how that makes me feel? But thank you for your input.